# Where should I ask a question about Ivan Illich (opponent of academia)?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation, scope

To me, [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), [Parenting Stack Exchange](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/), or [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) would be places to discuss unschooling and Ivan Illich.  Which Stack Exchange site would be most appropriate for such a question?

Here are the questions that I want to ask:

- How did Ivan Illich reconcile his dislike of academia with having been the vice rector of a University for years?
- Did Ivan Illich apologize for being part of the Catholic University of Puerto Rico or his subsequent teaching at different universities?  At some point he formed the opinion that schools cannot not help students.
- How did Illich reconcile his love of the Catholic Church with its many schools when he himself was so opposed to schools?

Answer (score 8):

This is a perfect question for [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

Ivan Illich was a philosopher, and a founding member of the "deschooling" movement. Questions about his thoughts and ideas, and how they interact with other philosophical schools of thought, are perfectly within the scope of Philosophy.SE.

The question(s) you've presented here are pretty well formulated already. My only recommendation if you decide to post on Philosophy is that you try and provide a bit more context. Perhaps a motivating quotation/excerpt and/or a reference to some background reading that you've done.

Only go to [Parenting Stack Exchange](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) if you have a *concrete, practical* question about how to raise kids in the context of deschooling. Like, how do I explain my socially radical ideas to my child and other parents? Or, how do I arrange for my child to have sufficient social interaction if they don't get that at school? It isn't for discussing the history or implications of systems of thought.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a fundamental issue with working out where these questions go is - they feel that they're about the *person* not the philosophy and implementations of them. I don't really feel unless you're Ivan Illich or someone whose field of study is about the *person* not just the writings of the individual in question, these questions can't be answered.

This rules out Parenting (unless you're asking about the applications of bringing up  child without schools) or academia (it feels like a bit about *life* as acedemia - and a quick read up on Ivan Illich kinda... gives me the idea its probably not a great fit).

The what's on topic  page for philosophy is unusual

I *presume* this might fit under

> history of philosophy — the domains and personalities in the past associated with philosophy

*BUT* it feels it might be a great idea to check on their meta first if possible, and I would *seriously* recommend reading through their [what's on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and the examples therein when formulating your question. I'm not a regular there and you may need to make your own determination on how best to tackle it

Comment: Nah, this falls under "applied philosophy" (and, to some degree, epistemology), and it's a perfect fit for the Philosophy site. You're right that it would not be at all suitable for Parenting or Academia.